# Set value by using other variable's value

Tags: scala, dictionary

I have a map, I wanna assign this key-value pairs from this map to a object, for example:

```
Person p = new Person
for k, v <- map
   p.k = map.get("k")
```

but I cannot actually use p.k, I tried p.${k} also not working, in this case, what should I do?

Comment: There's no type-safe way to do this in general. If the map is known at compile-time, you may be able to hack it with macros, but I strongly suggest you rethink your approach. It's likely you can organize your code in such a way that the dictionary is unnecessary

Comment: Please post the actual scala code, what you have posted is not scala. how is Person defined? what type of map is it? When you say it's "not working" what does that mean? if it's producing an error, post the error.

Comment: `if` for each field